# UITableViewController not being filled with NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, uitableview

I have a table view controller, FavoritesTableViewController and it has a mutable array "citiesArray". when a city button is pressed it calls a method which adds an object to the mutable array.

```
[self.citiesArray addObject:@"New York"];
```

it then logs the count of self.citiesArray as well as the array itself and appears to be working properly meaning that it successfully added the string "New York" to the array. So now I have a populated mutable array and want to fill the table view with it.

this is my code that doesn't appear to be working.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
       if (cell==nil) {
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
       } 
       cell.textLabel.text=[self.citiesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       return cell;
}
```

I've tried reloading my table view after but still doesn't work. Any ideas as to what the problem is?
thanks

Comment: Dont forget to check the table view delegate.

Comment: @pawan, the delegate has nothing to do with this problem. The data source could be the problem if the OP hasn't set it, but the delegate methods aren't relevant to getting the data to appear.

Comment: @rdelmar my fault, mistakenly i have written delegate, it should be datasource.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add method to return how many rows are in the table:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.citiesArray.count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Imlement the methods:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{  
    return self.citiesArray.count;
}
```

And, of course, if you haven't set the `datasource` and `delegate` property of your table, you should do it, for example in `ViewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //....Your code....

    table.delegate = self;
    table.datasource = self;
}
```

Comment: its the same posted by @Greg.

Comment: numberOfSectionsInTableView: is optional if you only have one section.